# @ManyToOne relation never read

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have to implement parent-child tree with EclipseLink.

The following code compiles Ok, reasonable DDL code is auto-generated, but the *children* field always resolves to an empty set, and tracing shows that **no queries** ever executed to fill this field.

```
@Entity
public class TreeNode {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  private TreeNode parent;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
  private Set<TreeNode> children;
}
```

Comment: Can you put the code for filling children?

Comment: public void addNode(TreeNode child) {
      child.parent = this;
      getChildren().add(child);
      emf.persist(child);
    }

Comment: The code that fill the database work excellent: I can read the objects in question back by plain SQL. The strange thing is the program emits no queries :-(

Comment: These queries are done internally. If youre using mysql you can see with MyAdministrator in Query log these (after enable the option to track them).

Comment: No, I switched MySQL logging on mysqld, there is no query still :-(

Comment: In fact, the tree is heterogeneous, TreeNode is an abstract superclass for some other classes.

Comment: Another hint: all objects read have NULL value in the parent field :-(

Answer (score 0):

AddNode seems to persist the child, but if it is not working on a managed parent, it will need to merge the parent so that the changes to the collection are stored as well.  Otherwise the changes made to parent are not stored in the cache, and so it will not show any changes until it is refreshed from the database.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the real class structure is not so simple, and that is the source of problem in EclipseLink:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
abstract class TreeNode {
  @Id int id;
  private TreeNode parent;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
  private Set<TreeNode> children;
}

abstract class NamedNode extends TreeNode { String name, title; }

class ConcreteNode1 extends NamedNode { ... some concrete fields }
class ConcreteNode2 extends NamedNode { ... some concrete fields }
....
```

Only ConcreteNodeXXX classes supposed to be instantiated, and all of them should inherit name and title fields from the abstract NamedNode class. EclipseLink does not complain, but fails to handle reading children from a several tables.

So eventually, I switched to Hibernate, and so far it handles this construct well.

Comment: You mentioned it wasn't querying the for the children, so i don't see why this would be affected by inheritance being used - it still seems it would have more to do with EclipseLink using a second level cache. Can you try refreshing the entity? If the children still don't get read, please file a bug with EclipseLink. Otherwise, the cache can be disabled if required, or kept consistent by merging the changes as mentioned.

Comment: I just started the program, read the parent object using a query, and explored the children slot. It contained an unitialized collection which turns into an empty collection as soon as I call any collection method on it without executing any database operation. BTW if I read the supposed children with another query, all they have NULL in the parent field :-(